# How to select a drop-down menu option value using Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I need to select an element from the below drop-down menu.

```
<select class="chosen" id="fruitType" name="fruitType">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">jumbo fruit 1</option>
    <option value="2">jumbo fruit 2</option>
    <option value="3">jumbo fruit 3</option>
    <option value="4">jumbo fruit 4</option>
    <option value="5">jumbo fruit 5</option>
    <option value="8">jumbo fruit 6</option>
</select>
```

I have tried using this code,

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='fruitType']/option[text()='jumbo fruit 4']").click()
```

but it returned me with errors.
How can I accomplish the same.

Answer (score 10):

From the [official documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms):

```python
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('fruitType'))
# Now we have many different alternatives to select an option.
select.select_by_index(4)
select.select_by_visible_text("jumbo fruit 4")
select.select_by_value('4') #Pass value as string
```

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate trough all options like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='fruitType']")
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options:
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
    option.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi please simply use one line code it will work

```
// please note the if in case you have to select a value form a drop down with tag 
// name Select then use below code it will work like charm
driver.find_element_by_id("fruitType").send_keys("jumbo fruit 4");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: For this answer i am getting the following error 

driver.find_element_by_id("fruitType").sendKeys("jumbo fruit 4");
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'

Comment: Sorry for python please use send_keys ,i am form java so it was a typo error also i have updated sendkeys for python

Comment: so is it like select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='fruitType' and @class='chosen']"))
        driver.find_element_by_id("fruitType").send_keys("jumbo fruit 4);  ??

Comment: no no select statement not this line select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='fruitType' and @class='chosen']")) .only this line driver.find_element_by_id("fruitType").send_keys("jumbo fruit 4);

Comment: Please use a universal wait for driver as error shows ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. apply something like wait of some seconds before option selection

Comment: will time.sleep(5) do ?

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds or time.sleep(NUM)